# Why does WordPress require a ftp server to be running on the webserver to transfer plugins?

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, ftp

I had asked a [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/313853) on Super User:

> A use case of a system "receiving" files over FTP would be, for example, the way WordPress plugins are installed via 1-click where WordPress initiates a file transfer to the local Linux box from the remote WordPress plugin repository using ftp(s)

More specifically this screen:

[image: WP asking for ftp info during plugin install]

My initial understanding that WordPress would transfer the files from the WordPress plugin repository, like how a FTP client would do. But [further discussions on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1419840#1419840) have left me confused as to why would WordPress require the FTP details of the web server?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do something that requires WordPress write to the filesystem, it does a check to see if it has permissions to do so by writing a temp file. If this check fails it will ask for FTP details in order to write the files to your server.

**EDIT**

look in `wp-admin/includes/file.php`, line 843, for the `get_filesystem_method` function that does this check.

Comment: It should be noted that non-direct access is not as well-supported by Wordpress. If FTP fails due to connection issue it could break a half-installed wp or plugin install, and there are other issues - see for example this bug: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29610

Comment: Is it possible to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

The **wp-admin/includes/file.php** **get_filesystem_method()** uses an erroneous test to determine if it can write a file. At line 853:

```
if ( getmyuid() == @fileowner($temp_file_name) )
```

The use of **getmyuid()** is wrong for unix - instead that should be **posix_getuid()**. The problem is the getmyuid() will return the owner of the script file not the user that is running the script. On unix, that means if the file was installed by root and the webserver is running as user www-data then test will fail even thought the file is written during the test.

So to fix, change the line with getmyuid() to:

```
if ( posix_getuid() == @fileowner($temp_file_name) )
```

Comment: Since it is part of core, you should not change it as the next WordPress upgrade will override it. If it is a bug you should probably report it here http://core.trac.wordpress.org/

Comment: How do you tell what user WordPress is running as?

Answer (score 2):

Milo's [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/23801/58142) is correct. I just wanted to add some details about how the check is done (because [`get_filesystem_method()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_filesystem_method/) has changed a bit since 2011).

Firstly, you can completely override this check by defining `FS_METHOD` in your `wp-config.php` to be `'direct'`, `'ssh2'`, `'ftpext'` or `'ftpsockets'`.

If this constant isn't set, then WP tries to determine what method to use. It does this by trying to create a temporary file called `wp-content/temp-write-test-1434788954` (that number at the end is just the current timestamp). If this file can't be created, it uses the `ssh2`, `ftpext` or `ftpsockets` method (i.e. the annoying ones that require authentication credentials).

If the file *can* be created, WP carries on to compare the owner of that file with the owner of `wp-admin/includes/file.php`. If these are the same, then all is good and the `direct` method can be used.

---

**TL;DR:** The web server user must be allowed to write to `wp-content/` *and* be the owner of `wp-admin/includes/file.php`.